# Form data in request is null when using ActionMapping/RequestMapping in Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc

When I try to acquire the data submitted in a form in Liferay 6.2 it returns null values as if the form data was being thrown away.

JSP:

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL var="link">
    <liferay-portlet:param name="action" value="doSomething"/>
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>
<form:form method="POST" action="${link}">
    <label>
        <select id="comboSelect" name="comboSelect">Options:
            <option value="1">FOO</option>
            <option value="2">BAR</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
@ActionMapping(params = { "action=doSomething" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doSomething(@RequestParam(value = "comboSelect") String selection){
    System.out.print(selection);
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either put a namespace prefix to your `name` value like this:

```
<input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace />inputTextName" />
```

or you can set the `requires-namespaced-parameters` setting to false in your `liferay-portlet.xml`.

This is a change since Liferay 6.2: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-aui-upgrade-tool/issues/30

They decided to make forms a bit more strict from 6.2. Making it false by default is still in debate on the Liferay forums, as far as I know, so it may become automatic, but for now you have to handle namespacing manually.